# Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' Error while doing Forgot your password

Tags: magento2, forgot-password

I am using Magento 2.3.3. when customer clicks on forget password and enters email address.
After clicking on Reset Password it gives this error Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress'

See https://prnt.sc/s7ronv

can somebody provide me solution for this.

Comment: i think you should run "composer update" command. In my case this worked after running other Magento commands like. php bin/magento setup:update php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Wear you getting the same error?

Comment: no, you try this

Comment: No, this did not work

Comment: @MohitPatel any other idea?

Comment: This is still not resolved. Can someone plz help